# Node.js Express server is not opening static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I got the express server running but when ever i try to load static files it shows an error
"Cannot GET /URL"
the files are inside a folder called "Login"
the app.js and "Login" are in the same directory

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
app.use(express.static("Login"))
```

Comment: the file is for example `./Login/file.png` and you open `http://localhost:3000/file.png`?

Comment: To help with these kinds of questions, we need to know several things.  1) What is the exact URL that is being requested of the server?  2) What is the current working directory when you run your program (since that will be used by express.static("Login") to resolve where to look for `Login`)?  3) Where is the `Login` sub-directory in your file system?  4) What file are you hoping to serve with the request from the URL in #1 (what is its full path on your disk).

Comment: the app.js and "Login" are in the same directory

Comment: yes exactly@wendt88

Comment: You can try: app.use(express.static(``${__dirname}/Login``));

Comment: Did you start your node process from the folder that has the `/Login` folder inside?

Comment: Cant reproduce this for express v 4.17.1 and on MacOS Catalina. What version of express are you running and what operating system are you running that on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"EDIT"

I found the solution by adding `__dirname` and a forwward slash to indicate the login folder

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Login'));`